# Reflect on struct type from reading a .go file

Tags: go, reflection, code-generation, introspection

I'm discovering generator (go generate) and I'm trying to generate Validation function for my struct.

The idea is that I don't want my program to use reflect at runtime, I would rather have a generator use reflect to generate the actual method I want to use.

the problem is I can't import my structs in the generator code, the only way I found so far was to read the .go file from the generator and manually parse the types defined there using regex

I've got something like

models/models.go:

```
package models

//go:generate go run ../generator.go -file models.go

type MyStruct struct {
    ...
}
```

generator.go:

```
package main

func main() {
    f, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fileName) // I read filename from the flag provided
    ...
    // I parse f to generate my stuff
}
```

I would very much prefer to have an introspection package that would take a go code as a string and give me some information about the struct defined there

Or maybe there is a way to import the file that call go:generate to get directly access to the types

Comment: Have you looked at the `go/parser`, `go/ast`, and `go/token` packages yet? You can read the file, and tokenize the code, and use it to generate code. There's plenty of examples of packages doing this out there. Google's own [mockgen](https://github.com/golang/mock/blob/master/mockgen/parse.go) springs to mind, for example

Comment: I'd recommend the `ast` package https://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/

Comment: I didn't know about these package, it looks like it's exactly what I'm looking for, Thank you

Comment: Reflection by definition is for runtime, not for parsing source code.

Comment: prefer to use go/loader and go/types to go/ast. go/ast is low level.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to specify file name , this code does the same :

```
//go:generate go run ../generator.go -file $GOFILE
```

With  help of  text/template package you are needless of parsing the file. A very simple example would be something like this. This will give you the clue :

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

//go:generate go run main.go -name=A
//go:generate go run main.go -name=B
//go:generate go run main.go -name=C

var name = flag.String("name", "test", "name of struct")

var code = `
package main

type Struct{{.}} struct {}

func (s *Struct{{.}} ) Vailadte() bool {
return true
}
`

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    file, _ := os.Create(*name + ".go")
    defer file.Close()

    tmpl, _ := template.New("test").Parse(code)
    tmpl.Execute(file, *name)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, using $GOFILE is nice, using template is not solving my problem though, it would help with generating the output code, but I still need to get the objects from the original file

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can utilize [go/parser](https://pkg.go.dev/go/parser) and [go/ast](https://pkg.go.dev/go/ast) in your generator.